# I could do it much simpler with Reflection. Should I?

Tags: java, reflection, factory

So I'm writing a game and I've come across a conundrum where I believe Reflection might be a better solution. But knowing that Reflection is discouraged and my other solution doesn't look that pretty, I thought I'd ask here and see what's actually a better idea in this scenario.

Essentially I've got an abstract card class, and will have several implementations of it. I have a case where I'm given a card name and need to construct an object of it, just given the name.

I know I could use either:

a) Reflection and use forName and invoke. It'll be very short code, scale well, and easy enough to write. That said, it's Reflection, and I'm all for avoiding it when I don't particularly need it.

b) Use a Factory design pattern and then have a giant conditional check, calling the appropriate class based on the name I supply. It's not difficult to write but requires constant maintenance and will take a while to write, plus it won't scale well. That said, it's a non-Reflection solution.

So what is the ideal solution? Do I just use Reflection because it keeps my code nice and short?

Comment: Reflection! Reflection! Reflection!

Comment: Personally preference is "B".  It's generally safer choice and allows for configurable solution (you could load a `Map` of names from a file which correspond to the class that should be instantiated for example).  Any time you think reflection is the right answer, you have a problem with your design.  I say this as I use reflection in a couple of places and am always looking for ways to reduce it...`Class.forName` isn't necessarily reflection ;)

Comment: Why not use a Factory design pattern, and start with your reflective implementation. I myself might consider a design based on a [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) myself (since a deck has such a limited number of cards / suits).

Comment: I agree with MadProgrammer -- if you need to use reflection, then you should first try to change your system so that you *don't* need to use reflection. If you absolutely must use reflection, then you have to do it.

Comment: This isn't a card game using a standard 52-card deck. The number of cards will most likely be a LOT higher than that. Think hundreds not tens.

I don't HAVE to use reflection but like I said, it's an extra 1000 lines of code that I have to maintain...

Comment: If performance is not an issue for you than go for First approach..

Comment: Where is the string coming from?  If it's coming from the UI or input by the player, Reflection doesn't seem to be a good idea.  If it's coming from elsewhere in your program, why are you using Strings to encode this data?

Comment: There are several different uses for this:

A testing class. Essentially we're going to encode a string representation of the game when we have errors in the game and then reload the game state so we can debug.

It's also going to come from the user in a front-end application, as they will send us requests that they're interacting with a card.

Also, performance is always an issue. I'm not sure how much the difference would be and how much it would affect but it will at least be relevant unlike in a lot of programs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative (not sure if it's the "ideal solution" like you've mentioned, but I think it's worth considering): enumerated types.  It will still be a huge list, but maybe a bit cleaner?  And you have to define them all somewhere.

An example of what I mean:

```
enum CardType {
  CARD_ONE(new Card(arg0, arg1, arg2, ..., argN)),
  CARD_TWO(new Card(arg0, arg1, arg2, ..., argN)),

  ...

  CARD_N(new Card(arg0, arg1, arg2, ..., argN));

  private final Card card;

  private CardType(Card card) {
    this.card = card;
  }

  public Card getCard() {
    return card;
  }
}
```

Then when you need to get one by name, just do:

```
public Card getCardByName(String cardName) {
  return CardType.valueOf(cardName).getCard();
}
```

This assumes the cards are singletons, but you could just as easily make the `getCard` method do some sort of factory logic to create a new one.

Comment: This doesn't seem better than anything I've already suggested, and they're not singleton, definitely not.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a factory pattern and use a prebuilt factory like Spring that you can use to define bean instances with there rather then implement your own factory.  It will scale easier as you can just define more bean types in either XML or annotated Java code.  Just make sure you use non-singleton beans and every time you ask your spring factory for a bean of a name it will call the constructor properly. It will even allow you to do dependency injection at the same time for free.

Comment: I think a BeanFactory is a little more than I need. I already know what I need these objects for and already know how I want to handle them for the duration of them being instantiated. I just know the Factory design pattern is perhaps a good idea to implement since it's almost by definition what I want to do.